# How to use voice command API in Android

Tags: android

I am new in android and currently working on small application that works on Voice Command API. For Example if I say bluetooth it will switch the phone's bluetooth to ON/OFF mode (vice-a-versa).

Please help me to do this....

Thanks in Anvance...

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's rather straight forward to use:

```
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    //uses free form text input
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    //Puts a customized message to the prompt
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
        getString(R.string.listenprompt));
    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Handles the results from the recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        //Turn on or off bluetooth here
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

And then call the `startVoiceRecognitionActivity()` from within your code wherever you need it. Of course you'll need to have the permssion to access the internet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

in your Android.manifest.

Comment: Sorry dear to reply so late because now i have used it. Its working very very good.

Comment: I am getting the Arraylist<String> of possible text value but how i can switch on/off the bluetooth.

Comment: That's a different question, but [lmgtfy](http://goo.gl/aB3be).